# how to track every actions on records with ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

How we can insert unique record to our types with ElasticSearch, for example 3 user updated the same record and we should store 3 record in our index with 3 `updated_by` and `updated_at` field. I'm using `Elasticquent` and now for example when i want to update a record from `course` table after that i do the bellow:

for example user with id `1` update the record.

```
$course = new Course();
......
.....
$course->save();

$course->updated_at = '2016-01-06'
$course->updated_by = '1';
$course->addToIndex();
```

and then user with id `2` update the same record

but inside index the document that created in first user update action is rewrite by the second user action.

Comment: You should provide more information, code samples of your own code, and what did you try so far. Check the [tour] page on how to format a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you need elasticsearch for this purpose. You can easily maintain a course_history table : id, course_id, updated_by, updated_at. Then to find any history of course editions, you can simply make a join. If you need document store for some performance benefits, I suggest choose some different one as elasticsearch is better for search and aggregations. It is not made for a document store. However, if this is really your requirement, then I would suggest maintaining a history table and then use associations with elasticsearch to make it searchable.

Comment: It means the things i want, is not possible with ElasticSearch ?

Comment: No. It means that it is doable in elasticsearch but I don't think it is the right use case for elasticsearch. Other NoSQL like MongoDB or RDMBS solves the purpose more beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

In such case it is better to store multiple documents. What you are trying to do cannot be done in a single document easily. An easier, and IMO better, solution is to store multiple documents. So with every update you sore new document. Recorc ID will be one of the fields you can search for afterwards.

```
[
    {
        "_index": "logs",
        "_type": "log_record",
        "record_id": 1,
        "updated_by": 100,
        "updated_at": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_index": "logs",
        "_type": "log_record",
        "record_id": 1,
        "updated_by": 200,
        "updated_at": "2016-01-01T01:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Now you can easily search for what you need and deleted specific records if necessary.

You don't really care about the decument ID here. You can let ES generate it for you. All you need is to store the correct record ID inside document.

Edit:

Here is how it may look in Elasticquent (please notice I don't know details of Elasticquent).

Lets say you have a class like CourseChageLog with the following mapping:

```
class CourseChageLog extends Eloquent
{
    use ElasticquentTrait;

    public $record_id;
    public $updated_by;
    public $updated_at;

    protected $mappingProperties = array(
       'record_id' => array(
            'type' => 'integer',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ),
        'updated_by' => array(
            'type' => 'integer',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ),
        'updated_at' => array(
            'type' => 'date',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ),
    );
}

CourseChageLog::putMapping();
```

The point is you need to ask the correct question. You don't ask how to store something. You ask what question you want to ask Elasticsearch and then you create an appropriate document form it. Don't create documents and then wonder if they can answer your question.

Comment: yes it is the solution of my problem, but with elasticquent how can i do that?

Comment: @jones I added a simple example but you have to figure out the rest. But I don't understand what is the problem. If you know how to structure a document then you should be easily able to do it in Elasticquent.

Comment: Still it's not clear for me, as you see in my question, elasticquent only have two method for indexing `addToIndex()` and `addAllToIndex()` that we can use to index the data. There is not any option to prepare the document our self, it just use from our model and mapping.

Comment: Exactly. And you control the model. Why can't you structure it the way you need it? I am not sure if I follow...

Comment: @awons In model only i define the mapping properties that has the same structure you defined in answer